# cloud run is closing the container even if my script is still running

Tags: google-cloud-run

I want to run a long-running job on cloud run. this task may execute more than 30 minutes and it mostly sends out API requests.
cloud run stops executing after about 20 minutes and from the metrics, it looks like it did not identify that my task is still in the running state. so it probably thinks it is in idling and closing the container. I guess I can run calls to the server while job run to keep the container alive, but is there a way to signal from to container to cloud run that job is still active and not to close the container?

I can tell it is closing the container since the logs just stop. and then, the next call I make to the cloud run endpoint, I can see the "listening" log again from the NodeJS express.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I want to run a long-running job on cloud run.

This is a red herring.

On Cloud Run, there’s no guarantee that the same container will be used. It’s a best effort.

While you don’t process requests, your CPU will be throttled to nearly 0, so what you’re trying to do right now (running a background task and trying to keep container alive by sending it requests) is not a great idea. Most likely your app model is not fit a for Cloud Run, I recommend other compute products that would let you run long-running processes as well.

Comment: what do you suggest for a cron job couple times a day running a docker with nodejs script that will scale to zero after done?

Comment: In that case, you can call Cloud Run from Cloud Scheduler (or other cron). If you keep the computing constrained to the duration of the request, and finish within Cloud Run’s request timeout, it should be okay.

Comment: So is there a serverless container engine in Google where u pay per CPU and memory usage like in Fargates? Something that let you run background threads and scale them up or down.

Answer (score 6):

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/quotas), Cloud Run will time out after 15 minutes, and that limit can't be increased.  Therefore, Cloud Run is not a very good solution for long running tasks.  If you have work that needs to run for a long amount of time, consider delegating the work to Compute Engine or some other product that doesn't have time limits.

Comment: I believe this time out is for the request. so if the server does not respond it will send 408 or a 5XX response. There is also documentation specify that if the server is not getting requests, it will close all container. if I do a simple get request every 15 - 20 minutes, the container still run and finish work even after an hour.

Comment: @nabulaer - Your code is not running in between HTTP Request / Response unless you are launching a background thread. The CPU is idled to zero when the last HTTP Response returns and makes the container eligible for shutdown. Cloud Run is designed for stateless HTTP services. Running background threads creates "state" which violates the container contract.

Comment: worth noting that there is a --no-cpu-thorttling flag now you can add to a Cloud Run to make sure a CPU is always allocated.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, You can use.You can create an timer that call your own api after 5 minutes, so no timeout after 15 minutes.Whenever timer executes it will create a dummy request on your server.

Answer (score -1):

Other option you can increase request timeout of container to 1 hour from 5 min, if your backend request gets complete in 1 hour